# netbeans 8.0.1 cant find shiro.ini

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, shiro

I added this `shir.ini` under web pages  under WEB-INF:

```
[main]
# Objects and their properties are defined here, 
# Such as the securityManager, Realms and anything
# else needed to build the SecurityManager
 shiro.loginUrl  = /index.jsp 
[users]
root  = 12345,admin
guest = 12345,guest

[roles]
admin = *

[urls]
/index.xhtml = authc
/login.xhtml = authc
/info.xhtml  = anon
/logout = logout
/admin/** = authc, roles[admin]
```

but in glassfish server 4.1 window, I got this error:

```
SEVERE:   [admin-listener(5)] INFO org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader - Starting Shiro environment initialization.
SEVERE:   [admin-listener(5)] ERROR org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader - Shiro environment initialization failed
SEVERE:   org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Shiro INI configuration was either not found or discovered to be empty/unconfigured.
```

Do you what it the cause or how to fix it?

Comment: I found the cause:
shiro.ini must be added under source packages not web pages

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily,

`IniWebEnvironment` class which extends `ResourceBasedWebEnvironment` specifies default configuration locations to `/WEB-INF/shiro.ini` and `classpath:shiro.ini`

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause: shiro.ini must be added under source packages not web pages