# Shiro ini not found or empty/unconfigured

Tags: shiro

I'm using NetBean 8.2 to learn how to use Apache Shiro but running into a deployment issue. When I try to debug the web app on Glassfish 4.0, I'm getting this error:

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Shiro INI configuration was either not found or discovered to be empty/unconfigured.
```

The error message is exactly like that found in this post: [netbeans 8.0.1 cant find shiro.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804499/netbeans-8-0-1-cant-find-shiro-ini). However, my Shiro.ini is already in WEB-INF folder (confirm by peeking into WAR file).

## Shiro ini

```
[main]
user.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = select password from users where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select name from roles where userid = (select id from users where username = ?)

ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
ds.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://<serverip>/<databasename>
ds.user = <username>
ds.password = <password>
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[urls]
/login.xhtml = user
```

## Web.xml

```
<listener>
<listener-class>
        org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>configPath</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:shiro.INI</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

With or without the init-param node, the same error is shown in the console log.

Comment: Where in WEB-INF folder?

Comment: Literally, just inside WEB-INF and not in WEB-INF/lib per Info-Q and BalusC's tutorial. In my earlier test using build in usernames in the INI, it would deploy to Glassfish.

Comment: Should be in `WEB-INF/classes`, as you are asking to load it from `classpath`.  Also if it is not Windows, case in name does matter, so `shiro.INI` and `shiro.ini` refer to different resources

Comment: No luck by moving it to WEB-INF/classes either. I also changed the capitalization of the filename and extension to match Web.xml (using Windows). Very odd that it used to deploy but it won't anymore. Tried restarting the machine and Glassfish.

Initial test didn't have init-param node and I had the ini file in the root web-inf folder.

Comment: This question as it stands now is not java-se or jsf-2.2 related

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it's the order that's the problem. Once I move the ds block before the jdbcRealm block, this specific error went away.

Comment: Both `WEB-INF/classes/` and directly in `WEB-INF/` will work.
Also, use lower case `shiro.ini` as that will work across different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Comment your shiro code in web.xml and try this (i think config path is making thing worst)

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Also first initialize your ds and only after that start configuring jdbcrealm so as you do not create some instance before initializing properties properly.

```
[main]
user.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
ds.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://<serverip>/<databasename>
ds.user = <username>
ds.password = <password>

jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = select password from users where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select name from roles where userid = (select id from users where username = ?)

securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[urls]
/login.xhtml = user
```